# 1064 error Can't Solve

Tags: mysql

```
 CREATE TABLE MEMBER (
MemberID     VARCHAR (255)         NOT NULL,
Email             VARCHAR (255)         NOT NULL,
Gender            CHAR                     NOT NULL,
Birthday           VARCHAR (20)
Education      VARCHAR (20),
Name             VARCHAR (20),
PRIMARY KEY (MemberID),
FOREING KEY (MemberID) REFERENCES LanguageSEARCH(MemberID),
FOREING KEY (MemberID) REFERENCES FAVORITE(MemberID),
FOREING KEY (MemberID) REFERENCES HISTORY(MemberID),
FOREING KEY (MemberID) REFERENCES TRACK(MemberID),
FOREING KEY (MemberID) REFERENCES WordSEARCH(MemberID),
FOREING KEY (MemberID) REFERENCES ORDER(BookMemberID)
);
```

```
Error:1064 (42000): use near'VARCHAR (20),
Name    VARCHAR (20),
PRIMARYKEY (MemberID),
FOREING KEY' at line 6
```

i have this problem i can't solve. I can add foreing keys later but i don't know how can i solve this.(Using MariaDB xampp)

Comment: You're missing a comma after the `Birthday` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add another var as primary key and not the attribute that you use for foreign key.

You miss one comma after "birthday"

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed the , after VARCHAR(20) for the column Birthday. Hence the error.